# what does the colon mean? I am searching for a long time on net. But no use

Tags: python-3.x

```
L = list(range(1,99,2))
s = L[:len(L)//2]#I want to get the first half of this list
print(s)
```

what does the colon mean in the 2 lines?

if I write the:, it prints 
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21,23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47], and it's exactly what I need.

if not, it only prints 49

Comment: It is used for *slicing*...

Comment: Upvoted. There's code here, and expected and actual output. It's still quite hard to search for this kind of thing.